# Integrating PayPal links to a php website

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal

I'd like to integrate PayPal links seen on this webpage:

http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/1340/paypale.jpg

The two links lead to this "checkout" page:

http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7087/paypal2o.jpg

I googled a lot which only left me even more confused.

I downloaded the PayPal PHP API from https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks but don't know where to start and what to look for in the API.

I think I need an absolute beginning guide, which I didn't find googling.

Comment: Have you looked at PayPal Merchant Services? They allow you to create carts, buy now and virtual terminals within your website. You can also assign product ID's to things you are selling. I imagine those ID's can easily be associated with items in a mysql database and then put into a button link PayPal gives you. You would just need to fetch the ID and attach it to the link to the PayPal store page. Some something like `href="http://paypal.com?=<?php echo['product_id']` should then link it to the item in paypal. I would play with methods like this an look deeper into the API and Merchant Serv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this site https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

That shoes you how to make a custom button, if you want to use a link though I think you need to use some JavaScript to make a link submit a form.